# Having trouble lining up text in css

Tags: css, html

I am pretty new to HTML5 and CSS and decided to try and make my own website to get my feet wet. I am looking to make a simpler version of http://www.igshoutouts.com/ to advertise my Instagram pages.
I am having trouble lining up the boxes such as putting the MEDIA, FOLLOWERS, and FOLLOWING along with the numbers in a box.
How do I get the MEDIA, FOLLOWERS, and FOLLOWING along with the numbers in each box.
I cant seem to line up the text where I want it on the page either. I was told not to put the text in CSS so how do I put it all

I have attached my code, please let me know how it looks so far.

```css
/* Base Styles -------------------- */

* { 
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  color: #878787;
  margin: 0;
  font: 1em/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {  
  font-size: 5.625rem; /* 90px/16px  */
  font-family: serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3;
}


 img {
  max-width: 100%
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Pseudo-classes ------------------ */

a:link {
  color: rgb(255, 169, 73);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: lightblue;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 169, 73, .4);
}

a:active {
  color: lightcoral;
}

.flex-item {
 color: black;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold; 
}

/* Main Styles --------------------- */

.main-header {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.625rem; /* 26px/16px */
}

.intro {
  font-size: 1.25em; /* 20px/16px */
  line-height: 1.6;  
}

.primary-content,
.main-header,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.primary-content {
 padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
}

.secondary-content {
 padding-top: 80px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

.callout {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding: 0 9px 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-footer {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ffa949;
}

.t-border {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

/* Layout Styles ------------------ */



.primary-content, 
.secondary-content {
  width:10%;
  box-sizing: border-;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin: left-side;
  max-width: 50px;
}


.box {

 background: url(igbodybuildingworld2.jpg);
 background-size: 150px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold; 
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 300px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
 height: 400px;
 
 
 
}


.box2 {
 background: url(absmotivation1012.jpg);
 background-size: 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
 height: 400px
}

.box3 {
 background: url(instafitnesslifestyle1012.jpg);
 background-size: 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
 height: 400px
}

.box4 {
 background: url(absinspiration1012.jpg);
 background-size: 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
 height: 400px

}
.box5 {
 background: url(gymcomedy1012.jpg);
 background-size: 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
 height: 400px
}
.box6 {
 background: url(instafitnesstransformations2.jpg);
 background-size: 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
 height: 400px
}
.box7 {
 background: url(motivation2squat2.jpg);
 background-size: 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
 height: 400px
}
.box8 {
 background: url(fitness_lifestyle202.jpg);
 background-size: 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
 height: 400px
}
 .box9 {
 background: url(gymlife222.jpg);
 background-size: 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:  top center; 
    float: left;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
 height: 400px
 
 .ad-left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Instagram Shoutouts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Instagrampage.css">
  </head>
  <body> 
    <header id="top" class="main-header">
      <h1>Instagram Shoutouts</h1>
   <span class="title">Increase followers with instagram shoutouts!</span>
      
    </header>
 
  
 

  
<p>igbodybuildingworld<br>MEDIA FOLLOWERS FOLLOWING<br>101 32K 321<br>Select Options</p>

</body>
</html>
 
  
  <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box2">absmotivation101</div>
        <div class="box3">instafitnesslifestyle101</div>
        <div class="box4">absinspiration101</div>
        <div class="box5">gymcomedy101</div>
  <div class="box6">instafitnesstransformations</div>
  <div class="box7">motivation2squat</div>
  <div class="box8">fitness_lifestyle20</div>
  <div class="box9">gymlife22</div>
        
   </div>

 
   
  </div><!-- End .secondary-content -->
    
 <html>
   <head>
   </head>


<style>
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 280px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
 border: 0px solid black;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: white;
 padding-top: 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:5px;
 margin-top: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">MEDIA</div>
  <div class="flex-item">FOLLOWERS</div>
  <div class="flex-item">FOLLOWING</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please study basic of html and css on site like w3school or on stackoverflow and then edit your question. html written above is looking wrong

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want but it may like below code

```
    <html><head>
    <style>
        /* Base Styles -------------------- */

* { 
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  color: #878787;
  margin: 0;
  font: 1em/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {  
  font-size: 5.625rem; /* 90px/16px  */
  font-family: serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3;
}


 img {
  max-width: 100%
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Pseudo-classes ------------------ */

a:link {
  color: rgb(255, 169, 73);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: lightblue;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 169, 73, .4);
}

a:active {
  color: lightcoral;
}

.flex-item {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align: center;
    }
.flex-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

/* Main Styles --------------------- */

.main-header {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.625rem; /* 26px/16px */
}

.intro {
  font-size: 1.25em; /* 20px/16px */
  line-height: 1.6;  
}

.primary-content,
.main-header,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.primary-content {
    padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
}

.secondary-content {
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

.callout {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding: 0 9px 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-footer {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ffa949;
}

.t-border {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

/* Layout Styles ------------------ */



.primary-content, 
.secondary-content {
  width:10%;
  box-sizing: border-;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin: left-side;
  max-width: 50px;
}


.box {

    background: url(igbodybuildingworld2.jpg);
    background-size: 150px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 400px;



}


.box2 {
    background: url(absmotivation1012.jpg);
    background-size: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px
}

.box3 {
    background: url(instafitnesslifestyle1012.jpg);
    background-size: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px
}

.box4 {
    background: url(absinspiration1012.jpg);
    background-size: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px

}
.box5 {
    background: url(gymcomedy1012.jpg);
    background-size: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px
}
.box6 {
    background: url(instafitnesstransformations2.jpg);
    background-size: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px
}
.box7 {
    background: url(motivation2squat2.jpg);
    background-size: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px
}
.box8 {
    background: url(fitness_lifestyle202.jpg);
    background-size: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px
}
    .box9 {
    background: url(gymlife222.jpg);
    background-size: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  top center;   
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px

    .ad-left {
  float: left;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>



    <title>Instagram Shoutouts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Instagrampage.css">


    <header id="top" class="main-header">
      <h1>Instagram Shoutouts</h1>
      <span class="title">Increase followers with instagram shoutouts</span>
    </header>

    <p>igbodybuildingworld
       <br>
       MEDIA FOLLOWERS FOLLOWING
       <br>
       101 32K 321
       <br>
       Select Options</p>

        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box2">absmotivation101</div>
        <div class="box3">instafitnesslifestyle101</div>
        <div class="box4">absinspiration101</div>
        <div class="box5">gymcomedy101</div>
        <div class="box6">instafitnesstransformations</div>
        <div class="box7">motivation2squat</div>
        <div class="box8">fitness_lifestyle20</div>
        <div class="box9">gymlife22</div>        
       <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-item"><p>12K</p><p>MEDIA</p></div>
            <div class="flex-item"><p>12K</p><p>FOLLOWERS</p></div>
            <div class="flex-item"><p>24K</p><p>FOLLOWING</p></div>
       </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

</body></html>
```